# Massive performance degradation in upgrade from MariaDB 5.5 to MySQL 8

Tags: query-performance, mysql-8.0, mariadb-5.5

As part of a complete server move and upgrade (OS, Apache, and db) went from MariaDB 5.5 to  MySQL 8.0.21. Hardware specs unchanged. Unfortunately despite many hours of reading and experimental tuning by both developer and sysadmin, performance is massively down. Some queries run OK on the new machine, but ANYTHING that requires any kind of table scan take seconds to many minutes to run (compared to always sub-1s on old install). A particularly bad example:

```
SELECT id,email FROM tickets WHERE key='md5stringkey'
```

*tickets* is MyISAM (on both installs) and some 700k rows long. *key* is not indexed. This query on 5.5 runs in 1s, but on 8.0 is ~20 minutes. Similarly a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets WHERE type='service' AND key='md5stringkey'
```

where *type* is indexed, will take between nothing and 60s depending on how many records of *type* are found. Would seem to suggest that a temp table is being written with the results of the *type* criteria then slowly scanned for *key*. In the case of *type*='service' there are 17k rows: takes 15s on mysql8, 0.8s with maria5.5.

mysqltuner says nothing other than "add 20x your physical memory" (5.5 ran fine with the same ram), performance schema uselessly shows all the time is spent in *executing* stage with no breakdown beyond that.

Oddly *created_tmp_files* is fairly low and *created_tmp_disk_tables* shows zero. Had assumed we were just writing to disk (spinners, unfortunately) alot. *key_reads* miss rate at below 0.2% but the keys involved in *tickets* are called constantly so doesn't seem likely that it would ever leave memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hardware specs unchanged. Same cpu’s? Same io cards? Same disks? Same sector sizes? Same core speed? Dedicated hardware? Database on own server? Dedicated storage? With the same execution plan such a change is extraordinary. Almost like a disc brake intervention.

Comment: Only difference is minor change in underlying HD specs but disk IO performance tests similar. And the problem queries do not appear to be reading from disk or writing temporary tables to disk anyway so disk performance shouldn't make a difference. If anything it appears to be CPU bound but same vCPU specs as previous install.

Comment: Does it run on dedicated cpu’s or thin provisioned?

Comment: Additional information request from new server RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Post on pastebin.com and share the links. From your SSH login root, Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; E) STATUS; AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - htop OR top for most active apps, ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Memory is unchanged and only spinners for storage. Servers are virtually identical including OS and software config. Difference is only newer OS and MySQL version. Hence the confusion about a large performance differential to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that pop up.

1. the optimizer became smarter
2. object statistics are wrong

To take the guessing out, compare the execution plans.
To understand the differences compare the optimizer statistics and see how you can make them more equal.

Maybe you must limit some of the newer optimizer choices.

Comment: EXPLAIN shows the identical plan on both instances, other than of course the new *partition* and *filtered* fields. Seems expected given how simple a query I'm dealing with (no joins even).

Comment: What happens if you just read the database files using dd and write to dev null? (and the same directly from the device?) do io sizes matter(count and bs variations)

Comment: Did a dd copy test early on to confirm FS performance. Definitely ballpark similar. While it is on a different physical machine the virtual server has the same specs and the underlying hardware is very similar (both same RPM spinners, no SSDs). Also worth noting that the example problem query above does not write a temp table to disk (per STATUS reporing).

Comment: Can you run the same version mariadb on the new system?

Comment: Not easily, given it is a production machine and would need ram added to allow it the overhead to run 2 instances of the DB. Besides which since the specs of the old and new VPS are so similar, it doesn't seem that it could explain a 20 to 1 (or worse) performance difference.

Comment: It can help to eliminate the differences in versions. How about the memory configuration (huge pages)?

Comment: Same on both VPSes. No hugepages in use. Set to 2MB.